# Changing DNS on IPv4 vs IPv6

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ipv6, ipv4

I want to change my `default DNS` to `Google DNS`.

Many sites like `streamble.com` are blocked in my default service provider DNS. After some research I found that, if we switch to `Google DNS`, we can access those sites.

But we have two protocol versions, `IPv4` and `IPv6`.

[image]

So which one is preferred to change the `DNS`, or whats the difference between these two when comes to changing `DNS`.

Comment: See more @ [Configure your network settings to use Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). If your ISP provides both IPv4 and IPv6 then you have to change DNS in both protocol. But there is no strict rule.

Comment: "So which one is preferred to change the DNS, or what is the difference between these two when comes to changing DNS." - Which one you should change depends on a variety of factors, including, if your ISP event assigns you a IPv6 address.  If you are only assigned a IPv4 address, then configuring the DNS for IPv6, wouldn't accomplish anything productive.  Edit your question to include the relevant information. Without knowing if you have a IPv6 it is not possible to answer your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are used for the two different internet protocol versions.

More than likely, you're going to be using IPv4 for all of your communication (IPv6 is used for some larger websites, but no where near as widely).

You'll want to change the IPv4 DNS Settings to Google Public DNS.